# SQL - Avoid 2 columns in 1 record having the same value

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm now working on a new MySQL database (interface PHPmyadmin) for my personal project and I don't know how to avoid two columns on a same table to have the same value. So, i want that we can't insert same values for 2 differents columns in one record.

Example

```
TABLE A

id name firstname
1  john   Marry   => will be possible
2  Marry   John   => will be possible
3  John    John   => won't be possible
4  test    test   => won't be possible
```

I want that two columns in same record can't have the same value

Comment: Define a trigger that checks the values to be inserted/updated and cancel the operation if they are the same.

Comment: But it's not possible to cancel action in Mysql trigger so if I create a new BEFORE INSERT trigger that checks WHEN value of column1 EQUALS value of column2, it won't be able to abort action.

Comment: Of course you can abort. Add `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'insertion aborted because ...';` in your trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use a CHECK constraint for that. Bu MySQL does currently not support them. It accepts the input but ignores them.

But you can use a trigger that cancels the insertion/update on certain conditions like this

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER check_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN        
    IF (NEW.name = NEW.firstname) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'same names error. Insertion canceled';
    END IF;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

You also need a trigger for updates doing the same.

Comment: Thank you, it works but I'm really surprised that we have to use an "old school" way to solve this kind of basic problem in MySQL. I'm using it to avoid "autolike" in a same table.

Comment: No idea what "autolike" is.

Comment: No matter it's just detail